# curl + Servidor HTTP Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, libcurl

Bom dia!

Criei um server HTTP utilizando nodeJS da seguinte forma:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.post('/', function(request, response, next) {
    console.log('body', request.body); // vai chegar aqui o  {"password":1138}
    console.log(request.body.password); // 1138
   response.send('OK!!');
});
```

Depois utilizei no terminal o seguinte comando:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"password":1138}'
```

A questão é que a linha `console.log('body', request.body);` retornou certinho o conteúdo JSON `body { '\'{password:1138}\'': '' }`, mas a linha `console.log(request.body.password);` me retornou `undefined`.

Não obtive nenhum erro, a questão foi que o `request.body.password` retornou undefined.

Cheguei até a trocar o trecho

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

por

```js
app.use(bodyParser());
```

E embora tenha aparecido a mensagem:

> body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares
>   body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node-modules\body-parser\index.js

Não apresentou erro, mas novamente o `request.body.password` consta `undefined`

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: O que te dá se fizeres `console.log('body', typeof request.body);`?

Comment: A linha "console.log('body', typeof request.body);" aparece como resultado: 
body object

Comment: Ok, e o que dá `console.log('body', Object.keys(request.body));`?

Comment: Aparece o conteúdo do json: 
body [ '\'{password:1138}\'' ]

Comment: Hmmm... essas barras são suspeitas! Os dados não estão a ser convertidos...

Comment: Testa juntar `app.use(bodyParser.json());` antes de `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({`

Comment: Estou usando as versões abaixo:

Express: "version": "4.14.0"
body-parser: "version": "1.15.2"

Não sei se isso tem algo a ver!

Comment: Testei a tua configuração e juntando `app.use(bodyParser.json());` funciona.

Comment: Usei assim:

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/', function (request, response, next) { 
    console.log(request.body);
    console.log(request.body.password);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1.:3000/');

Comment: cURL no terminal: curl -X POST http://localhost:3000 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"password":1138}'

O resultado continua sendo:

{ '\'{password:1138}\'': '' } //console.log(request.body);
undefined //console.log(request.body.password);

Estranho!

Comment: Essa configuração funciona bem para mim (em Mac)...

Comment: huumm... estou usando Windows 7... vou dar uma pesquisada sobre isso!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Resolvi!

O problema estava na forma que o cabeça~ho estava sendo passado no curl.
Debugando eu vi que o cabeçalho no Nodejs não estava como Json sendo que eu tinha passado no curl

No comando cURL eu acrescentei um -i antes do -H:

curl -X POST http://localhost:3000 -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"password":1138}'

Ai o resultado apareceu certinho no console.log(request.body); e no console.log(request.body.password);

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Boa! Coloca como resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi!

O problema estava na forma que o cabeçalho estava sendo passado no curl. 
Debugando eu vi que o cabeçalho no Node.js não estava como JSON sendo que eu tinha passado no curl.

No comando cURL eu acrescentei um `-i` antes do `-H`:

```
curl -X POST localhost:3000 -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"password":1138}'
```

O resultado apareceu certinho no `console.log(request.body);` e no `console.log(request.body.password);`

Obrigado pela ajuda!